# Delete button added to new row and delete row/move sheet

Tags: excel, vba, button

Trying to do something I havent tried before and no idea where to start.

**AIM**: When a new row is added and the sheet created, as in the code below; I want a DELETE button added to each new row, when this is pressed, ask for confirmation from the user and then delete that row and move the associated sheet to a different workbook (WorkBook_Archive.xlsm) with the date included prior to the original sheet name (gives a unique identifier).

```
Private Sub NewServer_Click()

Dim shtName As String, ws As Worksheet
Dim wsMASTER As Worksheet, wsTEMP As Worksheet, wsGENERAL As Worksheet
Dim shNAMES As Range, nmANCHOR As Range
Dim eRow As Long, wasVISIBLE As Boolean
Dim shANCHOR As Range

With ThisWorkbook
Set wsMASTER = .Sheets("Main")
Set wsTEMP = .Sheets("ServerTemplate")
Set nmANCHOR = wsMASTER.Range("E10:E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

wasVISIBLE = (wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetVisible)
If Not wasVISIBLE Then wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetVisible

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

wsMASTER.Unprotect Password:="J786djh$"
Do
    wsMASTER.Activate
    shtName = Application.InputBox("Please Enter Name For New Server" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
             "Click Cancel To Quit", "Define Sheet Name", Type:=2)
    If shtName = "False" Then Exit Sub
    Set ws = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = Sheets(shtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Do
    MsgBox "Please try again, ensuring no spaces are used in the new server name.", vbExclamation, "Name Exists"
Loop


    eRow = wsMASTER.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    wsMASTER.Cells(eRow, "E").Value = shtName

    wsTEMP.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = shtName

    Set shANCHOR = wsMASTER.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
        wsMASTER.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=shANCHOR, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & shtName & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=shtName

    For Each wsGENERAL In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If wsGENERAL.Name = "ServerTemplate(1)" Then
        wsGENERAL.Delete
    End If
    Next wsGENERAL

wsMASTER.Activate


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
wsMASTER.Protect Password:="J786djh$"
End With

    If wasVISIBLE Then wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetHidden Else: If Not wasVISIBLE Then wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetHidden

End Sub
```

I am assuming the position of the button matters, for the purposes here, the button will be in **Column F** starting at **line 10**.

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer your question. I've been down this road many times and adding a button to a row is totally doable, but it's a lot of work to maintain and there are a lot of edge cases/issues that pop up. You may want to consider using the built in events to manage these actions. When I want to give the user the ability to delete a row (often corresponding to a row in a database in the backend) I have them double click the row. That can be caught automatically by excel with the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick()` event. It's super simple and really difficult to mess up then.

Comment: Hmmm... Ok, that does sound like a decent solution but unfortunately, this is for 3rd party distribution and need the simplicity there with as little instruction as possible. Is this "edge case/issue" situation you mentioned in relation to resizing of the sheet or columns etc? the sheet is protected so will not be changed in any sort of sizing way...do you think this will still occur?